# iTunes suddenly rejecting mp4 downloads from torrent networks

Tags: itunes, macos, video, encoding

For a while I have been able to add most videos coming from torrent network without problems unless they were avi encoded. But for a few weeks now, I have had to re-encode all of the mp4 videos that I download using Handbrake which is not very practical.

Why is this? Does everyone face the same issue as I do?

iTunes v 11.1.5
OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks)

Comment: describe rejecting?

Comment: drag and drop fail silently

Answer (score 1):

MP4 is a media container format which can be encoded with many different video and audio codecs like DivX, Xvid, H.264, H.263, MPEG-4, AC3, WMA, AAC, etc. While iTunes only support few video and audio codec like MPEG-4 video codec and AAC audio codec; H.264 video codec and AAC audio codec. If the MP4 video is encode with iTunes unsupported video or audio codec, iTunes will not add and play it.

Sometimes, even if the MP4 is in the right video and audio codec that iTunes supports and we can successfully add and play MP4 in iTunes, but if the MP4 video does meet the technical specifications for iOS devices like video size, bitrates, sample rate and etc, we will fail to sync and transfer the MP4 video from iTunes to iPod, iPad, iPhone, Apple TV and etc.

A recommended solution is to convert iTunes unsupported MP4 to a more compatible MP4 video format using [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr).

Comment: know all this thank you the question was more what new format is everyone encoding into so that most files do not go on itunes anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Video is complex!
MP4 is just a container!

Video have these key elements
Containner, Video, Audio, subtitle, Chapter info, METADATA cover pictures.

I could tell you what iTunes or iOS need for video
Containter must be MP4 (m4v m4a) and MOV
Video is H.264 (only 8bit are allowed,not 10bit, r-frame must not excied 16)
Audio (must in AAC, ALAC, or AC3 format, if the video only have mp3 or DTS, it won't add)
Subtitle only in SRT or Closed captions. no ass/ssa allowed.

most video don't come with DETADATA and cover pictures.
only the video from iTunes store or my Torrents.
for example
https://www.nyaa.se/?page=view&tid=800429

Comment: How does this differ from previous answer